# MATLAB: Choosing area of focus and center of rotation on 3D sphere plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following code that produces a sphere with a Mars texture overlaid on its surface,

```
R = 3.39e6; %Radius of Mars (m)
mars_texture = imread('mars.jpg');
[x,y,z] = sphere(100);
surf(R*x,R*y,R*z)

h = findobj('type','surface');
set(h,'cdata',mars_texture,'facecolor','texturemap','edgecolor','none')
```

[image]

However, what I would love to be able to do is have the 3D plot focus on a particular point on the surface of Mars (as in the example given below), and to also have that point act as the center of rotation, instead of the usual point at the origin. Would such a thing be possible? [image]

Comment: you want the _view_ to rotate? or the actual object?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have explained that better. I'd like the object to stay static, and I'd like the view to rotate about a particular point on the surface of Mars (not rotate automatically, but rotate about a point on the surface of Mars where the user manually decides to rotate the 3D plot).

Comment: Ah, I see. That's an interesting problem. My approach would be to use [this functionality](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#zmw57dd0e274973) to capture your mouse movement (or possibly, even more easily, left and right mouse button events to rotate clockwise / anticlockwise respectively) and then use that to control the "azimuth" and "elevation" values for the `view` function, such that it produces the rotation around the axis that you want choice (you'll have to figure that out mathematically I'm afraid!)